# Can't find element in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I have been working on this problem for quite a bit now, and can't figure out why this is happening. I am trying to click a button. The button and the corresponding text always changes, but the XPATH stays the same.
[Button I am trying to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNjzr.png)
It doesn't work with CSS Selector either. I am using Chrome web version 106. Does anyone know why?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

PATH = r"C:\Users\###\Downloads\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)


# time to login
driver.get("https://clever.com")
time.sleep(60)

try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[2]').click()

except NoSuchElementException:
  print("no such element")
  pass

time.sleep(5)
```

[Capturing the XPATH for the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u44X4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[2]').click()
```

May be you using not correct syntax

Comment: still didn't find the element

Comment: What message error?

Comment: no error, it just passes and gives me the message "no element found"

Comment: So it's very likely that your Xpath is not correct

You can try using wait if it still doesn't work then you should post the link here
`driver.find_element("xpath","//input[@value = 'hearing']")`

Comment: tough to post the link, but I'm almost 100% confident that it's correct. I can't post the link since I need to log-on through my account to access it. The website is Launchpad Learning curve. Perhaps I have to change the iFrame? do you know anything about this?

Comment: You should capture code HTML (tree), don't capture UI

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean by capturing HTML code rather than the UI, I added a picture of how I capture the XPATH in the main post at the bottom, could you take a look? Not too sure but I saw something online about changing the iFrame.

Comment: Yep, you are on the right track with iframe
you can see that element is inside another iframe in HTML code
if you haven't switched to that iframe it will error
anw, try switching to that Iframe and try using the syntax I pointed to `find_element("xpath",xpath your element)`

Comment: what is "xpath your element"??